# How to interact with objects with ARFoundation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

So the idea is to have a plane and grid placement system in augmented reality with the ability to place and move characters on grids. I already have an example for a mobile device, I have a script that generates grid and a script that allows me to place objects and it works just fine, however, I can't figure out how to use all of the above and if it's possible in AR. For example, I want to detect a plane then instantiate a level and put some objects on it.

Here's the script that is attached to the GridManager and is used to make a grid:

```
[SerializeField] private float size = 0.05f;

public Vector3 GetNearestPointOnGrid(Vector3 position)
{
    position -= transform.position;

    int xCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.x / size);
    int yCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.y / size);
    int zCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.z / size);

    Vector3 result = new Vector3(
        (float)xCount * size,
        (float)yCount * size,
        (float)zCount * size);

    result += transform.position;

    return result;
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    for (float x = 0; x < 40; x += size)
    {
        for (float z = 0; z < 40; z += size)
        {
            var point = GetNearestPointOnGrid(new Vector3(x, 0f, z));
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, 0.01f);
        }

    }
}
```

and here's the one that's attached to the PlacerManager and used to place objects on the grid:

```
private Grid grid;

private void Awake()
{
    grid = FindObjectOfType<Grid>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            PlaceCubeNear(hitInfo.point);
        }
    }
}

private void PlaceCubeNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
{
    var finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
    GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform.position = finalPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the raycast options to identify different objects

Answer (score 0):

Raycasting and/or colliders are the way to go.

The sample scene in AR Foundation has a script called PlaceOnPlane.cs that shows how you can detect when a user touches the screen. E.g:

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
        if (m_RaycastManager.Raycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position, s_Hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                // Raycast hits are sorted by distance, so the first one
                // will be the closest hit.
                var hitPose = s_Hits[0].pose;

                if (spawnedObject == null)
                {
                    spawnedObject = Instantiate(m_PlacedPrefab, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
                }
            }
}
```

This allows you to get the screen touch position and then raycast from it to the real world scene. In this example, a game object is instantiated in that location. For your case, you can instantiated a level if your hit a plane or a plane exist around the hit position.